# Adding a column in table A when using condition in table B

Tags: php, mysql

So I want to find a sum of column "Calories" in table "foods." But I want to find the sum

```
where a.id = b.foodid 
  AND b.username LIKE '$user' 
  AND b.day='$day' 
  AND b.month LIKE '$month' 
  AND b.year LIKE '$year' ORDER by b.id DESC
```

Currently I have this: but its not working

```
$caloriesum = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT SUM(calories) 
                                               FROM foods a, 
                                                    user_foods b 
                                              WHERE a.id = b.foodid 
                                                AND b.username LIKE '$user' 
                                                AND b.day='$day' 
                                                AND b.month LIKE '$month' 
                                                AND b.year LIKE '$year' 
                                           ORDER BY b.id DESC")) or die(mysql_error());
```

Then I later make the script echo out the sum.

```
            echo('  
            <tr class = "db-out-head">
            <td><b>Totals</b></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>'.$caloriesum[0].'</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </tr>');
```

And all I see in an empty table.

Comment: What isn't working? What is your tabnle structure? Do you get an error message?

Comment: You really shouldn't wrap `mysql_fetch_assoc()` around `mysql_query()`, as it will fail if the query fails.

Comment: Also, don't do `or die()` along with `mysql_fetch_assoc()` because if no rows are returned on a valid query, the fetch call will return `FALSE` and you'll execute `die()` which isn't appropriate since there's no error, just no rows for the query.

Answer (score 0):

remove your ORDER BY :), so the sql like this :)

`SELECT SUM(calories) FROM foods a, user_foods b WHERE a.id = b.foodid AND b.username LIKE '$user' AND b.day='$day' AND b.month LIKE '$month' AND b.year LIKE '$year'`

Comment: It's still not working.
I'm then trying to echo the sum out. using this:

    echo(' 
    <tr class = "db-out-head">
    <td><b>Totals</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>'.$caloriesum[0].'</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>');

Comment: order by doesn't affect sum by it's presence or absence.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for exact match then use equal to operator.
Try this query:

```
SELECT SUM(calories) FROM foods a INNER JOIN
user_foods b ON a.id = b.foodid AND b.username LIKE '$user' 
AND b.day='$day' AND b.month LIKE '$month' AND b.year LIKE '$year'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you create an associative array `$calories[0]` won't work. Give that sum a name in your query and use that as array index.